# Rotating Black Holes

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, speed-of-light, event-horizon, causality

All stars rotate. And the more they contract the faster the rotation, so is there such a thing as a non-rotating black hole? And as gravity is less at the equator of a rotating star, assuming that they are still stars after collapsing to become black holes, at a very high rate of rotation could the escape velocity at the equator be less than $c$ while away from the equator it exceeds $c$? The fact that they still rotate and have a gravitational field after becoming black holes suggests that they are still stars even though we can’t see them, and gravity should still be slightly less at the equator of the spherical event horizon.

Comment: One question per question, please! A rotating star cannot have an escape velocity of *c*.

Comment: In some basic sense, you are right. The horizon is farther away from the center of a Kerr black hole on the equatorial plane that is at the poles. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric#/media/File:Kerr-surfaces.png Also, all astrophysical black holes are presumably Kerr black holes, yes.

Comment: What if it collapses to become a black hole? We don't know what goes on inside the event horizon,though some people pretend that they do. Its worth remembering a quote from Bertrand Russell,who knew a thing or too about mathematics himself: "Mathematics is the subject in which we never know what we are talking about,nor whether what we are saying is true." Obviously he was speaking tongue in cheek,but he was only half joking. I think he had quantum mechanics in mind when he said it.

Comment: @Michael Walsby  "don't know what goes on inside the event horizon" we don't, but we have no reason to believe our theory fails right after the event horison. The equivalence principle of GR tells you, that unless the tidal forces are really huge, there is no reason to believe the theory breaks. And for supermassive black holes the tidal forces right after the event horizon can be weaker than on Earth.

Comment: @FeynmansOutforGrumpyCat has answered your question(s), but I reckon that your main problem with all that is that you seem to be really thinking in newtonian terms, hence your "they are still stars even though we can’t see them, and gravity should still be slightly less at the equator of the spherical event horizon". I suggest you find a good popular science book about GR.

Comment: I have read lots of popular science books & I know there's supposed to be a singularity in there where the laws of physics as we know them break down,but nevertheless the black hole still has dimensions, it still has a large gravitational field,  and usually its rotation is a lot faster than some commentators are willing to admit,so I don't see why we shouldn't treat it as a star.

Comment: @Michael Walsby To some extent, we're talking English here, not physics:  A star is an "incandescent" (i.e., shining) body, and other languages I read define it in the same terms. Still, your observation about the weaker gravity at a star's equator seems valid, and I was surprised that it wasn't explicitly mentioned in Wikipedia's item "Penrose process", about the hypothetical extraction of energy from rotating black holes that involves a division of projectiles in their oblate region.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby You shouldn't treat black holes as stars because they are not. For starters, stars are supposed to be made of matter. A black hole is just a region of spacetime and has no matter whatsoever.

Comment: @FeynmansOutforGrumpyCat  I think we agree that BHs are (temporarily, per Hawking, or permanently, per older views) causally separated from our region as not even light signalling can escape their gravity, but there are some bouncing cosmologies that require a BH to White Hole bounce within BHs.  The bounced material is particulate, produced by the intense gravitational field of the collapsing star.  The idea traces back to Smolin and Gasperini, but Nikodem J. Poplawski has a version of inflation based on it; see his 2015 "Non-parametric reconstruction of an inflaton potential" .

Comment: Two points: when a white dwarf has eventually cooled down it will not be incandescent but it will still be a star ( I wonder if any have yet done this,if not in our galaxy then in others), Second point: There must be matter inside a singularity,albeit in a form we don't understand,as its presence is given away by its gravitational field. People who claim they know what goes on inside a black hole are deceiving themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the expectation is that all (astrophysical) black holes have at least some rotation. Strictly speaking the chance of one having exactly zero rotation is zero. However, the rotation can be so slow that the non-rotating solution is a good approximation.